# Jenkins doesn't recognize Allure command

Tags: maven, testing, jenkins, report, allure

Hello Allure generators,
I'm trying to make Allure accessible to our testers in the company. I've installed Allure 2 through Scoop in the server and I'm able to run the cmd script: "allure serve" and see the results. So far so good. Now, my basic thought for solution is : run a "Post build actions" with a "Post build tasks" plugin with the allure serve command. The result is not good:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 27.801 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-25T11:08:28Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Performing Post build task...
Match found for : : True
Logical operation result is TRUE
Running script  : cd C:\Projects\CarambolaClientTest2\target
allure serve
[Suite_runner] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins6058556997605873748.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Suite_runner>cd C:\Projects\CarambolaClientTest2\target 

C:\Projects\CarambolaClientTest2\target>allure serve 
'allure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Projects\CarambolaClientTest2\target>exit 9009 
POST BUILD TASK : FAILURE
```

How can it be that "'allure' is not recognized.." ? It recognized it through the cmd (I've added it to the Environment variables of the machine and also to the environment variables in Jenkins configuration under Global properties).

I've also tried:

1. Create a Batch file with the script and run it in the post build
   task (got the same result).
2. Add the Allure Plugin- but that's a
   whole new problem- I'm getting an empty report.
3. Create new Job that only runs a "Windows batch command" with the allure serve, and it is running "Down stream" after the main Job runs (its the 2nd
   project). Getting the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have allure executable in your PATH. Try to reload jenkins slave (or master) to see changes if you've added it to PATH before.
Also you can make Jenkins install allure automatically - find the a plugin for that

Comment: 1- When I used Scoop to install Allure it inserted "ALLURE_HOME" in the "User variables" with Value: "C:\Users\Administrator\scoop\apps\allure\current" (Its not in the System variables). Also, I did "jenkins restart" and it still isn't recognized... 2- When using the auto install from the plugin- is it installing each build?